# Is this a genuine bitcoin minning app?

Tags: blockchain

[image]
Please can someone explain if this is a  genuine app for bitcoin mining?

Comment: Almost certainly not.

Answer (score 1):

No, a mobile device cannot mine bitcoin.

These days, mining bitcoin requires specialized computer hardware called ASICs. They are loud and hot, and incredibly efficient at computing the SHA256 mining algorithm. A mobile device is not like this at all, it is not optimized to compute SHA256, it is meant to be a general-purpose device. Trying to mine bitcoin using a mobile device would be a literal waste of money (electricity), and you would receive no bitcoin in return, because your device would not contribute a meaningful amount of hashpower to the network.

The app is likely malicious, I would remove it from your device.